# From where does an electron get its charge from?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, charge

I have read often that charge, like mass, is an intrinsic property of an electron. But even the mass is due to its interaction with the Higgs Field. So is there something which explains where the electron, or any fundamental particle for that matter, get its charge from?

Comment: A good answer is this https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/226844/46708

Answer (score 2):

As far as anyone knows, the charge is a fundamental property of the electron, with no deeper explanation.

One thing that is curious is that the charges of quarks come in exactly 1/3 or 2/3 fractions of the charge of the electron. This implies, among other things, that atoms are exactly neutral. A priori, there is no reason for these quantities to be related. In some Grand Unified Theories, the charges of the quarks and electrons are related because they fall under the same representation of the unified gauge group. However, this is speculative and we do not have experimental evidence in favor of (or completely ruling out the entire class of) Grand Unified Theories.